# node.js and edge.js - continuously running task (thread)

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, task, edge.js

I would like to make a running task (ListenResponse()), which continuously listens and sends data to serial port. At the same time, I would like to add another task (WriteParameter) through which I would set some parameters, which are then sent to serial port. The problem is, that now I'm using two async tasks, but the data in thread is not getting updated fast enough. It updates after few iterations of ListenResponse() task.

Pseudocode is below:

```
string data;
void ListenResponseSerial() {
    byte b;
    while (true) {
        b = getSerialData(&b);
        parse(b);

        if (parsed) {
            Respond(data);
        }
    }
}

public async Task<object> ListenResponse(dynamic input) {
   (new Task(ListenResponseSerial)).Start();
}

public async Task<object> Write(dynamic input) {
    IDictionary<string, object> payload = (IDictionary<string, object>)input;
    data = (string) payload["data"];
    return null;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What language and environment is this code from?  It doesn't look like Javascript, but you have it tagged as node.js.  How is node.js involved with this code?

Comment: jfriend: It is a part of application written in c#. This code gets executed through node.js and edge.js.